# ref keyword and wrapper methods

Tags: c#, c, interop

I have an interface, IProxy, and an implemenation Proxy.  The purpose of the proxy is to wrap some extern functions which call into a C library.  For the extern declaritions this requires that the structs be passed using the ref keyword. Here's a sample:

```
namespace CFuncs {
  [DllImport("cLibrary.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
  public static extern int MyCFunc(ref MyStruct result);
}

public interface IProxy { public int MyFunc(MyStruct result); }

public class Proxy : IProxy { 
  public int MyFunc(MyStruct result) { 
    return CFuncs.MyCFunc(ref result);
  }
}
```

The function declartion from the C header file:

```
int MyCFunc (MY_STRUCT* result);

typedef struct  { 
  // some fields
} MY_STRUCT;
```

And the calling code:

```
var proxy = new Proxy();
var result = new MyStruct();
proxy.MyFunc(result);
```

My question is should I be using ref in the wrapper interface and implemenation as well, or will the struct be properly filled with data by the C function?

EDIT:  The code presented as a sample DOES seem to work.  Could that be that even though the C library wants a pointer it never actually does change it?  Is ref a requirement for interop-ing with functions that take pointers?  The sample C code that comes with the library always has the caller allocating memory for the structs it takes, if that means anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.NET uses call by value, and moreover `struct` is a value type -- hence, if you want it changed by an external function, it should be a `ref` parameter.